# Bootstrap alert content is not visible properly when scrolling

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to create a bootstrap alert, which will display always in the top. I am able to do that.
The problem is, when I scroll the page, other page contents are displaying over the alert box. I tried z-index, but is not working. Please help.

Here is my code,

```
<div class="container" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="65">
    <div class="alert alert-block alert-success">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        Success Message
    </div>
```

Comment: Are you doing some modifications? Coz if not this should work fine. Can you paste the whole code?

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle example?